# Typescript - Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript

I have typescript function which accepts multiple object types and need to do something depending on the type of object for 'toAddresses' parameter, but i keep getting the 2 errors.

```
function createEmailClient(fromAddress: string | Email, toAddresses: (string | Email)[], subject: string, content: string, contentType: ContentType): EmailClient {
  const recipientAddresses: Email[] = []

  if (typeof toAddresses === 'string') {
    toAddresses.forEach(function (address) {
       const recipientEmail: Email = {
          email: address.toString(),
          senderName: ''
       }
      recipientAddresses.push(recipientEmail)
    })
  } else if (typeof toAddresses === 'Email') {
     recipientAddresses.push(toAddresses)
  }
```

1. 'Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'never' for array iteration.
2. This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"' and '"Email"' have no overlap.ts(2367)

is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing without other unrelated problems.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w8KAPW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: It can't compile your `if` blocks because you are type-checking for values that are not arrays. `string` will never have a `forEach` property. You will probably face the same issue with `push` and `Email`.

Comment: You're testing an array with [the `typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) at runtime, and that will always be `"object"`.  It won't be `"string"` even if the array holds string elements, and it *certainly* won't be `"Email"` because that's not the kind of thing `typeof` ever returns.  It seems like you are confused by TS's static type system and type erasure.

Answer (score 1):

I beleive you want to do something like this:

```js
function createEmailClient(fromAddress: string | Email, toAddresses: Email | string[], subject: string, content: string, contentType: ContentType): EmailClient {
  const recipientAddresses: Email[] = []

  if (Array.isArray(toAddresses)) {
    toAddresses.forEach(function (address) {
       const recipientEmail: Email = {
          email: address.toString(),
          senderName: ''
       }
      recipientAddresses.push(recipientEmail)
    })
  } else {
     recipientAddresses.push(toAddresses)
  }
}
```

Comment: `Email | string[]` isn't the same as `(string | Email)[]`

Comment: True that, but I think that was a glitch regarding what the rest of the code is trying to do.